# What are the required styles for a Material UI palette?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some components that use the `MuiThemeProvider` to customize a button.  The reason is probably because you can only have `"primary"` or `"secondary"` instead of a custom palette name.  They look like this:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { badTheme } from "./Themes";
import {
    Button,
    MuiThemeProvider,
} from "@material-ui/core";

class Widget extends React.Component {
    render() {   
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={badTheme}>
                <Button color="primary">Click me</Button>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default Widget;
```

The `badTheme` here is just the app theme with an override for `main` in the `primary` palette.

```js
const badTheme= createMuiTheme({
    ...defaultTheme,
    palette: {
        ...defaultTheme.palette,
        primary: {
            main: "#2B368B",
        },
    },
});
```

It would be nice to get rid of these little themes that just change a button, so I want to know what are all the styles I need to implement when switching to `withStyles`.

I don't want to lose the ripple style or any other style I'm not aware of that is seeded from setting `main` in the palette.

What does it take to replace `MuiThemeProvider` with `withStyles`, or whatever else, and having the exact same styles on this button that are seeded based on the `main` palette setting?

Comment: Just a suggestion... you might change the title of this question to  "how to define custom button colors using withStyles," or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Button variant has its own color styles, which are defined in  [Button.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js).

To create new button colors using withStyles (instead of the `color` prop), you will need to replicate the color-specific styles for the desired variant.

As of material-ui@3.1.1, these are the styles to create a custom button color for each variant.

#### Text buttons

Color styles for the default button variant. Based on [`.textPrimary`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8995f085904eb55bcb5861fb6d8a32fbd38d72eb/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L50-L59)
*Note: These styles are also applied to the outlined variant.*

```js
textPink: {
  color: pink[500],
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: fade(pink[500], theme.palette.action.hoverOpacity),
    // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
    "@media (hover: none)": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }
  }
},
```

#### Outlined buttons

Color styles for outlined button variant. Based on [`.outlinedPrimary`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8995f085904eb55bcb5861fb6d8a32fbd38d72eb/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L84-L92)

```js
outlinedPink: {
  border: `1px solid ${fade(pink[500], 0.5)}`,
  "&:hover": {
    border: `1px solid ${pink[500]}`
  },
  "&$disabled": {
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.action.disabled}`
  }
},
```

#### Contained Buttons

Color styles for contained/raised button variant. Based on [`.containedPrimary`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8995f085904eb55bcb5861fb6d8a32fbd38d72eb/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L131-L141)

```js
containedPink: {
  color: theme.palette.getContrastText(pink[500]),
  backgroundColor: pink[500],
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: pink[700],
    // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
    "@media (hover: none)": {
      backgroundColor: pink[500]
    }
  }
}
```

**Complete Example:**

[image: Edit Material UI Custom button colors]

Comment: Super helpful!  Seems like the ripple effect is "colour agnostic"?  Do you happen to know?

Comment: Glad this helped! The ripple effect uses css `currentColor`, so it automatically matches the text color of the button.